# Implementing an android/java based application that takes an audio file and and generates the guitar tab to the audio file?

Tags: java, android, audio, fft, midi

Which audio format will be easier to work with in JAVA? MIDI or MP3?
How to extract the note frequency from the audio file in java? 
and how is it possible to display the guitar tab with respect to the audio track that is imported to the application? Are there good **java API**'s i can work with?

Found out the FFT algorithm which converts a signal from its original domain.

Comment: Your question is way too broad (and it isn't a single question). See [help/on-topic].

Comment: I suggest searching the academic literature for research papers on attempted solutions, perhaps on the MIREX competition forum.  An bare FFT is quite unreliable at extracting note pitch frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is far easier to work with MIDI than MP3 files. Java exposes MIDI, and MIDI directly encodes standard keyboard note pitches as integers. Working with MIDI files, there would be no need to do any frequency analysis of raw audio data. In addition, decoding MP3 requires the use of external libraries (I may be wrong, in terms of JavaFX) and the decompression of the audio data as well as raising the question as to whether you need to pay the owners of the MP3 patent a licensing fee.

If you work with MIDI, the conversion to guitar tabs is pretty easy. For example, MIDI note value of 69 is A-440, which is the the 4th string, 2nd fret. Subtract 12, for 57, and you have A-220 which is the 2nd string, yes? (I may be counting my strings backwards, or be off by an octave! I'm not up on guitar specifics.) In any event, it is easy to find charts online:
[Note names, MIDI number and frequencies](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html)

For more on working with MIDI, see the Java Tutorials: [Overview of the MIDI package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/overview-MIDI.html) I think you would want to pay attention to *ShortMessage.NOTE_ON* for reading the note values.

On the other hand, it is easier to load and play back sound files than MIDI files. However, the analysis required to extract pitches of a given instrument (especially if there are other instruments also playing) is far above what I know how to do.